# Angular|Express|Mongoose got HttpErrorResponse error status: 404

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, https

Does anybody have issue like this? I'm trying to upload data from form with img. Using `multer` on backend(for img). My post request working good and save data to database. However, I got big problem to `fetch` all this `data`.

1. my post request

```
router.post('/admin-product-data', multer({ storage: storage }).single('image'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");
  const product = new Product({
      size: req.body.size,
      group: req.body.group,
      classification: req.body.classification,
      pattern: req.body.pattern,
      variety: req.body.variety,
      model: req.body.model,
      product_code: req.body.product_code,
      price: req.body.price,
      imagePath: url + "/images/" + req.file.filename
  });
  product.save()
      .then(createdProduct => {
          res.status(200).json({
              message: 'admin-product data fetched successfully',
              data: {
                  ...createdProduct,
                  id: createdProduct._id
              }
          })
      })
});
```

and then how looks data on database

```
_id:60348211ea5d9a6e6ea3e079
size:12
group:dsfsf
classification:sdfgds
pattern:sdfag
variety:afdgfdag
model:adfgfda
price:12
imagePath:http://localhost:3000/images/10.jpg-1614053905362.jpg
__v:0
```

this is my get route(he does not response even if I put `console.log()` in body `function`;

```
router.get("/admin-product-data", (req, res, next) => {
  Product.find().then(documents => {
      console.log(documents);
      res.status(200).json({
          message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
          posts: documents
      });
  });
});
```

When I'm trying to fetch via postman I got some `buffer logs` in my `console` -

```
>    <Buffer 3c 21 64 6f 63 74 79 70 65 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d
> 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 20 20 3c
> 6d 65 74 61 20 63 68 ... 8791 more bytes>
```

and on the front end -

```
> GET http://localhost:4200/admin-product-data 404 (Not Found) and
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not
> Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/admin-product-data", ok: false, …}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I expect the issue is related to registering those routes, but since the post request is working I suggest putting the get request at the same file if it is not there

Comment: I tried the same code on my own setup, it works fine